# Box-api V2 upload file curl php returns false

Tags: php, curl, box-api

I´m trying to upload a file from PHP via Box-API v2 and I only get a **boolean false response.**
I think this is caused by CURL, not Box-API but I was fighting the last five hours, and I can´t find the solution. Any idea??
The implicated code is that: 
note: the file exists and is accessible from code and the token is ok (other calls to API work fine)

```
const CONTENT_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/';
$file = "unexeceles.xlsx";

private $defaultOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT    => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    );    

public function putFile($file) {

        $options = $this->defaultOptions;
        $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array ("Authorization: Bearer ".$this->token);
        $options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $postfields = array();
        $postfields["filename"] = '@'.$file;
        $postfields["parent_id"] = 0;

        $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $postfields;
        $handle = curl_init(BoxConfig::CONTENT_ENDPOINT."files/content");

        curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);

        $response = curl_exec($handle);

        curl_close($handle);
        if (is_string($response)) {
            $response = $this->parse($response);
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution.

The problem was the relative path to the file, the file exists and it´s accessible form code, but CURL seems to need the entire path to the file.

Very helpful the function curl_errno($handle)

> if(curl_errno($handle)) {
>
> ```
> echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($handle);
> ```
>
> }